# Apache: How to prevent site viewers from seeing my folders?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a website url that looks something like this: `www.test.com/folder1/test.html`

If I change the url to `www.test.com/folder1` I can see all the files and folders parallel to folder1. I don't want people to be able to do this and see these folders and files. How can I block access to this?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the document root. The file is located at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` if you use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn off the Indexes option. You can do it in a .htaccess file for a directory, in the configuration file for the site in a <Directory> section, or the global configuration httpd.conf.

```
 Options -Indexes
```

This will prevent the server from generating an navigable index of files.

Full documentation is here: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options